# temporary css changes by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a custom toggle switch on my website, which can be switched *ON or OFF*. Depending if it is *ON or OFF* (checked or unchecked) there are different `CSS` classes applying to the switch and changing the style.

I want to turn this toggle switch *on / off* using javascript. However a change of the status *"checked / unchecked"* does not make a change. This leads to me having to adjust the `CSS` style of the switch to turn it e.g. *OFF*.

However, this leads to the problem now. When I change the `CSS` using javascript, I basically add styles to the element directly. This leads to the normal toggle switch `CSS` not working anymore as the element style overrides any class style. If i assign an additional class to the switch , the normal style overrides the class. using `!important` is not an option, as it stay permanently *OFF / ON*

Is there any way to apply `CSS` to an element, without automatically disabling the default `CSS` style changes?
like setting a `CSS` style until the next normal change happens?

**HTML**

```
<div class="onoffswitch active" id="recurringdiv">
  <p>Recurring</p> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked=""> 
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch" data-click-state="0" id="recurringfield"> 
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner custom1"></span> 
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch custom2"></span>
  </label> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.onoffswitch-label').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
      /*Click State 1 finish*/
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
      /*Click State 2 finish*/
    }
  });
});

<!-- This is the autopay -->
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.auto-onoffswitch-label').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
      /*Click State 1 finish*/
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
      /*Click State 2 finish*/
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.auto-onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .auto-onoffswitch-label .auto-onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
.auto-onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
```

Comment: `.auto-onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .auto-onoffswitch-label .auto-onoffswitch-switch` what is that html?

Comment: Are you adding styles with .css()? If I understand correctly, why not just use .addClass() to add a class?

Comment: <div class="onoffswitch active" id="recurringdiv">
                  <p>Recurring</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked="">
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch" data-click-state="0" id="recurringfield">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner custom1"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch custom2"></span>
                </label>
                </div>

Comment: when adding a class !important has to be used, which overlays future changes again

Comment: you have `auto-` prepended to your class names in your css styles, but not in your class names in the html, is that an error in typing this question?

Comment: No I have two toggle's one for autopay and  the other for recurring payments. I'm just using the same code but naming them different classes so they both can work at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the status of the element using CSS/ normal jquery I would recommend using a click event.

```
if (condition == true) {
jQuery(".onoffswitch-switch").trigger('click');
}
```

Its simple and should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Tom that solved it! Impressive it was that simple.